# CRm Dynamics 2013 Plugin Error, Request for the permission of type xxx failed

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a CRM Plugin that fires on an update of a field on the form, the plugin then should utilize the Import capabilities of the SDK to Import CSV Records into Dynamics, I get the foloowing error

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

I have registered the Plugin in Isolation Mode set to NONE, not Sandbox but I still get the error, any Ideas as to why this is happening and how I can resolve it. It fails on the ImportFile part which is encapsulated in the ImportData function.

Please see my Plugin Code below

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("loaclContext");
        }

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            Entity supplyClaimsEntity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            if (supplyClaimsEntity.LogicalName != "new_supplierclaimsupdate")
            {
                return;
            }

            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));

            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);

            string entityBeginUpload = "Start Upload";
            try
            {

                string filePath = (@"C:\Team CRM\Warp.csv");

                ImportData(service, new_topproducts.EntityLogicalName, filePath);

            }

            catch (FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
                Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: {0}", ex.Detail.Timestamp);
                Console.WriteLine("Code: {0}", ex.Detail.ErrorCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Detail.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
                    null == ex.Detail.InnerFault ? "No Inner Fault" : "Has Inner Fault");
            }
            catch (System.TimeoutException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
                Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
                    null == ex.InnerException.Message ? "No Inner Fault" : ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                // Display the details of the inner exception.
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);

                    FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault> fe = ex.InnerException
                        as FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault>;
                    if (fe != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: {0}", fe.Detail.Timestamp);
                        Console.WriteLine("Code: {0}", fe.Detail.ErrorCode);
                        Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", fe.Detail.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine("Trace: {0}", fe.Detail.TraceText);
                        Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
                            null == fe.Detail.InnerFault ? "No Inner Fault" : "Has Inner Fault");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a synchronous (Asynchronous could potentially be running on a different server, depending on your deployment) plugin, check that the IIS Account the user is running as has rights to the folder.  If it doesn't then you'll get the file permission error that you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the plugin on an online organisation? In that case you can't set the organisation set to mode when you register the assembly.

Comment: Hi Marco, this is an on-premises version of CRM actually, I set the mode to None but still no luck, as Sandbox mode cannot access the file system , I get the same error either way, any idea?

Comment: I see that you are using Console.WriteLine on a plugin, that would not sort any effect, and that you are trying to access C:\Team CRM\Warp.csv. Is that your local drive or the server one? I doubt CRM has the rights to access that location even outside the sandbox

Comment: It is on my local machine, and yes I have also added it to the server as well, so what do you suggest, how else can I get this working?

Comment: You should try to read from a directory where CRM will have read permission (for instance the CRM installation folder, or a folder where the User running the Application Pool in IIS will have right permissions)

Comment: I have done all the above, the file is on the CRM app server, I have given the Async service user access to the folder, as well as the calling user (myself) on the folder as well, I am really battling to understand where the issue is, as it still fails with the same error. The plugin is registered out of sandbox mode. I have also attempted to place the file in the CRM installation folder "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb\Warp.csv" , but still no luck. I am running the code off my local machine.

Comment: What happens if you Place it in the folder described in the code above and give everyone all access to the folder?

Comment: A simple question: why can't you include the file as a web resource and access it through the url CRM assigns to it?